# Why does form_for helper require index path for a new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my routes file

```
resources :details, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :new]
```

and in new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@detail) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
<% end -%>
```

and in the details controller

```
  def new
    @detail = Detail.new
  end
```

When the new.html.erb is rendered, I get the following error message

```
undefined method `details_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc4ac6bd730>:0x007fc4b62e7390>
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this is that the the form_for helper is looking to post to `/details`. So it is not looking for the index path but the :create path.

So you need to add the :create action to your routes declaration

```
resources :details, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :new, :create]
```

If you look at the rendered html in this case, it will look like this

```
<form class="new_detail" id="new_detail" action="/details" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
```

so you can see why you need the :create path which makes the post /details path.

Answer (score 1):

The create and index actions use the same path but different actions. So if you have either in the routes file, then a `details_path` method will be generated. In your case you want to make sure you have the create in your routes file:

```
resources :details, only: [:create, :show, :edit, :update, :new]
```

Answer (score 1):

To give context to your answer, you need to look up about the [`resourceful`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) nature of Rails' routes:

> Browsers request pages from Rails by making a request for a URL using a specific `HTTP` method, such as `GET`, `POST`, `PATCH`, `PUT` and `DELETE`. Each method is a request to perform an operation on the resource. A resource route maps a number of related requests to actions in a single controller.

When you say... "`form_for` helper is looking to post to `/details`", it's *actually* looking to post your form data to the `create` method. The way it does this is through the `POST` verb on the `/details` route:

[image]

Thus, you need to ensure that you're declaring your `create` route if you wish to use the resourceful routing structure.

This is why you'll need the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :details, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :new, :create]
or
resources :details, except: :index
```

--

Of course, you *don't* have to use it.

You can use whichever routes you want. The important thing, though, is to understand that Rails is built around [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration); [HTTP's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Technical_overview) is towards [`resources`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource):

> The server, which **provides resources** such as `HTML` files and other content, or performs other functions on behalf of the `client`, returns a `response` message to the client

This is why you have "resourceful" routing etc.

On top of Rails' [object orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) nature, you need to appreciate which resources are being used at certain points in your app.

`form_for` expects a `new` object to route to the `create` route. You can override this by using the `url:` option:

```
<%= form_for @object, url: none_resourceful_path ...
```